# Mapping an ArrayList and another internal Map with String, Integer

Tags: java, arraylist, maps

EDIT: I just changed the TreeMap to HashMap and now it works a litttle bit but still doesn't do what I need it to do..

Hey,this is something I have been stuck on for a really long time.

My goal is to take text from a file `sequence.txt` and then call a constructor that passes a scanner `s` and an integer `n`. Inside of the constructor my goal is to read `n` words from `sequence` and save that in the ArrayList, and then the inner map is supposed to be able to take the word immediately following that sequence of `n` words and keep count of how many times n + thisWord exists.

So, an example would be these n (or 5) words:

`so an to me for`

And then the sixth could be `and`, so in the original map it would be:

map.put(arrList, innerMap);

where arrList would be contain `so, an, to, me, for` and the innerMap would look like this `and | 1`

And then from there on each new one would be added and for the same sequences it would increment the integer by one. I would be worried about the second part, but I can't even get my code to work, and I don't know what I've done wrong. Here is my constructor:

```
public RandomWriter(Scanner s, int n) {
        Map<String, Integer> valMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        this.s = s;
        this.n = n;
        map = new HashMap<>(); `

        Queue<String> tmp = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tmp.add(s.next());
        }

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
            tmpList.addAll(tmp);
            String current = s.next();

            if (!valMap.containsKey(current)) {
                valMap.put(current, 1);

            } else {
                valMap.put(current, valMap.get(current + 1));
            }

            tmp.add(current);
            tmp.remove();
            map.put(tmpList, valMap);
        }

       // s.next();
        System.out.println(map.keySet());
    }
```

Upon changing to HashMap it now prints out like this:

`[[today, day], [me, and], [so, if], [in, for], [for, you], [top, in], [sent, receive], [for, many], [on, top], [or, on], [do, do], [side, so], [so, when], [under, on], [many, much], [to, do], [row, on], [for, when], [when, become], [dog, house], [toy, your], [many, is], [won, do], [become, inside], [why, to], [to, spell], [me, you], [school, under], [too, your], [hit, high], [can, do], [is, to], [for, how], [receive, get], [on, me], [animal, your], [to, animal], [inside, to], [your, for], [cat, many], [who, me], [spell, word], [do, cat], [house, live], [how, can], [your, who], [word, sent], [to, today], [canvas, word], [on, for], [low, ball], [which, many], [animal, if], [much, mouse], [live, living], [your, sent], [if, how], [high, kill], [ball, hit], [if, so], [in, side], [get, which], [you, if], [so, for], [do, if], [get, toy], [so, row], [if, to], [to, if], [win, won], [how, when], [inside, in], [dog, squirrel], [you, to], [and, you], [so, or], [word, school], [mouse, for], [for, why], [day, dog], [squirrel, fish], [your, if], [cat, dog], [for, which], [to, when], [more, for], [to, your], [which, cat], [living, canvas], [kill, win], [you, low], [when, inside], [fish, animal], [do, so], [many, more], [to, too], [when, to]]`

This is the map it is entering into:

`private Map<ArrayList<String>, Map<String, Integer>> map;`

Comment: It is unclear how you're getting the values for the "inner map" from your description.  As to the error, it's because `ArrayList` is not comparable (and thus cannot be stored in a `TreeSet`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong :

```
        if (!valMap.containsKey(current)) {
            valMap.put(current, 1);

        } else {
            valMap.put(current, valMap.get(current + 1));
        }
```

You probably want :

```
        if (!valMap.containsKey(current)) {
            valMap.put(current, 1);

        } else {
            valMap.put(current, valMap.get(current) + 1);
        }
```

Since if the map contains the key `current`, you want to add `1` to the value of that key and not overwrite it with the value of key `current+1`, which may not even exist.

Comment: Yep this is correct.. I don't really even know what my original problem is now though. I'll add output to OP

Comment: @brian I find it impossible to understand what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: thats probably why it doesn't do what I want it to do

Comment: I've added the code for the map that it is supposed to be representing if that helps you understand

Comment: @brian What is this map supposed to represent? Can you explain that? I don't understand how the first n words you read are related to the rest of the words, and why you are using a list as the key to a map.

Comment: the overall purpose is to take the map "map" and generate random text using the generateRandomText(int numWords) (this isn't shown b/c it has no code). The outputted text is meant to be the original first "n" words followed by a random letter from the inner map, where the integer in <String, Integer> is the weight, so the ones with higher should be printed first.

Comment: @brian Why do you keep adding and removing stuff from the `tmp` list of the origninal n words? Shouldn't that list stay constant?

Comment: My professor recommended it because this is how it works: it checks the first two (if n is 2) so "to you" and then if the third is "me" then itll add "(to, you) | (me | 1)", then the next check will dequeue "to" and enqueue "me" and check "you me" and whatever is right after "me"